# Method for equal arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

beginner here!

I am trying to write a boolean method that returns `true` if the two arrays a and b have exactly the same elements in the same order, and `false` otherwise.

Although, I am having a problem with comparing two null arrays, for which i want it to return true if:

```
int [] A = { };

int [] B = { };
```

My code so far is:

```
public static boolean equalArrays(int [] a, int [] b) {
    if(a.length == 0 && b.length == 0)
        return true;
    else {
        if(a.length == b.length)
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++)
                if (a[i] == b[i])
                    return true;
    }
   return false;
}
```

EDIT1: Fixed the code above

EDIT2: Another problem is when i try testing

```
int [] A = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int [] B = {2, 3, 4, 6, 5};
```

It returns true when it is supposed to return false. Anyone have any idea on where the problem is?

Comment: You are comapring 2 `empty` arrays, not null arrays!

Comment: It seems the OP uses “null array” inaccurately to mean an array of length 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is inside your for loop. It should be:

```
public static boolean equalArrays(int [] a, int [] b) {
    if(a == b){
        return true;
    }

    if(null == a || null == b){
        return false;
    }

    if(a.length != b.length){
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++){
        if (a[i]!=b[i]){
            return false;
        }
     }

    return true;
}
```

Note that I swapped the places of `true` and `false` and now check for `!=` instead of `==` That's because we want all elements to be equal, not only a few of them.

As BackSlash commented, I added checks for null

PS: You should use brackets -> it makes the code much more readable

Comment: @Tom No it's not wrong -> notice the `    if(a.length != b.length){` But thanks, for the note :)

Comment: It will still throw an exception if one of the arrays (or both) is null

Comment: That's why I explicitly said, that it assumes non null arrays, as the original code, but I can add checks for null, although that was not the original issue in the code

Comment: Then it was wrong and you fixed that while I wrote the comment, because I saw the unfixed version.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Yes, but the question explicitly says `Although, I am having a problem with comparing two null arrays`

Comment: @BackSlash and has given an example with **empty** arrays :) Either way I added checks for null

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
int [] A = { };
```

Is **not** a null array, it's an *empty* array.

> Although, I am having a problem with comparing two null arrays

You could do something like this:

```
if(a == null && b == null) {
    // both arrays are null
    return true;
}

if(a == null || b == null) {
    // one of the two arrays is null, they are not equal
    return false;
}

if(a.length == 0 && b.length == 0) {
    // Both arrays are empty, they are equal
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I admit we’re trying to hit a moving target here: you haven’t addressed the other issue, EDIT2, in the question. It seems quite important too. (I did not downvote)

Comment: @OleV.V. The downvote came when no edits were done :) Anyway, a comment in this case would be much more useful, as we don't receive notifications on updates, so we cannot know whether the post has been updated or not. It would be better to leave a comment saying "You didn't do this" instead of downvoting with no reason. Downvoting with no reason is like having a teacher that gives you F on an exam and says "Yeah, I wanted to give you F, I'm not going to explain you why". Totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Arrays.equals`

```
public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

It is always better to do basic length, null checks before iterating each elements in both the arrays

Comment: Good point. No need to reinvent the wheel. This code handles empty arrays (the askers first concern) entirely correctly (it returns false if arguments are null, which may or may not be what one wants).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean equalArrays(int [] a, int [] b) {
    if(a.length == 0 && b.length == 0)
     return true
    else {
     if(a.length == b.length){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++){
            if(a[i]!=b[i]) 
             return false; 
        }
     } else return false;

    }
   return true;
}
```

plese use this code thanks :) i already check wether the two arrays are null

Comment: This code is wrong. You only check if you find at least one element which is equal and return `true` then, ignoring the other elements. And you didn't check if the arrays are `null`, just if they are empty. `null` and empty are different things in Java.

Comment: This works well so far, although when testing another two arrays

Comment: It works well as long as you provide equal arrays. If you use different arrays, which have the same first element, it will return true instead of false. [Demo](http://ideone.com/IudXsZ)

Comment: @BackSlash Well, any element can be equal, even the last one, but you're right, this code can't detect non-equal arrays then.

Comment: I cannot be compiled.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. Your code still fails to detect non-equal arrays if the first item is equal (and the others aren't).

Comment: sorry hehe this is the last time

Comment: This now returns `true` if both arrays aren't empty, but have different sizes (the elements in their don't even matter).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
  public static boolean comparearr(int a[] ,int b[])
    {
     if(a.length!=b.length)
     {
        return false;
     }
      else 
       {
         for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
         {
           if(a[i]!=b[i])
           return false;
         }
       }
     return true;
   }
```

Note:
also when you say

```
int a[]={1,2,3};
and int b[]={};
```

in first case `a` is an array initialized with 1,2,3 so the length property will yield length=3 but in case of `b` it will be set to 0 as its not null array its just empty array with length=0 because of `{}` definition

Comment: We don’t really need the `if(a.length>0)` before the for loop. If lengths are 0, the for loop would just execute 0 times (that is, be skipped) and we’d come down to the `return true` at the bottom, which gives the correct result. So I’d prefer to simplify the code and leave out the second if-else construct.